# Missing end statement in algorithm2e environment

Tags: algorithm2e

I used `\SetKwProg{myproc}{Procedure}{}{}` for starting my pseudo-code with `Procedure` keyword. But its `end` statement (the last `end` in pseudo-code) is not appear in the result pdf. So how can i bring it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\SetKwFunction{proc}{BuildEBTM}%
\SetKwProg{myproc}{Procedure}{}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\SetKwFunction{connect}{Connect}
\SetKwData{ce}{ce}
\myproc{\proc{}}{
    \Input{A Process $M$}
    \Output{A Process $EM$}
    \BlankLine
    \ForEach{FlowElement $e$ in $M$}{
        \ForEach{Converter $c$ in $Converters$}{
            \If{$c$ accepts $e$}{
                \ce $\leftarrow$ $c$ converts $e$\;
                \connect($EM$,\ce)\;
            }               
        }
    }
}
\caption{my procedure}
\label{my_procedure}
\end{algorithm2e}
\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```

The result pdf without last `end` statement:

[image: result pdf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`CTAN`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), the last argument of the `\SetKwProg` command sets the end text.
So get that 'end', the builder for the `\myproc` command should be

```
\SetKwProg{myproc}{Procedure}{}{end}
```